# Why NSTextField only shows the first word

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

When I include an `NSTextField` to a view, the added data is not completely shown. When the same configuration is applied to an `NSTextField` added with the .xib the text is shown completely.

Here is the code:

```
// Generated programmatically
NSTextField *label = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
[label setBezeled:NO];
[label setDrawsBackground:NO];
[label setEditable:NO];
[label setSelectable:NO];
label.alignment = NSCenterTextAlignment;
label.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [NSColor redColor];
label.font = [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.f];
[label setStringValue:str];
[self addSubview:label];


NSSize s3 = [str sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}];
NSLog(@"S3 size: %f", s3.width);
[label setFrameSize:s3];
```

And the result is this:

[image: Black text is the label configured in xib file. White text is the label created in xib file and configured programmatically. Red text is the label created and configured programmatically]

Black text is the label configured in xib file. White text is the label created in xib file and configured programmatically. Red text is the label created and configured programmatically

Any idea?

The code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/argosen/labelsampleosx/overview)

Comment: Try to increase width.

Comment: In XCode, run your app, then go to Debug/View Debugging/Show View Frames. This will visually show you how big all the views are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NSString`'s `sizeWithAttributes:` only calculates the size of the text string itself. An `NSTextField` and its `NSTextFieldCell` also require some room themselves to handle their part of the drawing. So when you set the cell size to the size of the text alone, it's too small for the cell to draw all of the text and so the text is truncated.

Instead of trying to measure the size of the text yourself, you might try:

```
[label setStringValue:str];
[label sizeToFit];
[label setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

`NSTextField` inherits `NSControl`'s [`sizeToFit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/sizeToFit) method which will automatically resize the text field to the appropriate size.